# KNN with categorical values can not predict correctly

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, knn

I am trying to build a model that given an item, predicts which store it belongs to.

I have a data-set of ~250 records which are supposed to be items in different online stores.

Each record is composed of: 
`Category,Sub Category,Price,Store Identifier(The y variable)`

I have tried several number of neighbors, tried Manhattan distance but unfortunately can not get better results accuracy ~0.55. 
Random Forest produces accuracy ~0.7.

My intuition says that a model should be able to predict this problem. What am I missing?

This is the data:
https://pastebin.com/nUsSbkp4

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

labelencoder_X_0 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_0.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])

onehotencoder_0 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder_0.fit_transform(X).toarray()

onehotencoder_1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder_1.fit_transform(X).toarray()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
# classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=25, criterion='entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='minkowski', p=2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

accuracy = classifier.score(X_test, y_test) 
print(accuracy)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KNN *can* potentially produce good forecasts with categorical predictors. I have had success with it before. But there is some stuff not note then:

- the numeric variables have to be on the same scale, e.g. by using [min-max scaling](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)
- one could try specicfically desined error metrics such as the [Gower distance](https://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2012/ams/slides/v4.2.pdf)

Besides that though, you actually have a bug in the one-hot-encoding:

After calling the first one hot encoder you have an array of shape (273, 21):

```
onehotencoder_0 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder_0.fit_transform(X).toarray()
print(X.shape)
print(X[:5,:])

Out:
(275, 21)
[[ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   52.   33.99]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   52.   33.97]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   36.   27.97]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   37.   13.97]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   20.    9.97]]
```

Then you call the one hot encode on the second column which  had only two values (zero and one) and hence results in:

```
onehotencoder_1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder_1.fit_transform(X).toarray()
print(X.shape)
print(X[:5,:])

Out:
(275, 22)
[[ 1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   52.   33.99]
 [ 1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   52.   33.97]
 [ 1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   36.   27.97]
 [ 1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   37.   13.97]
 [ 1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.
   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   20.    9.97]]
```

So, if you could fix that or simply use for instance pipelines to avoid that and add the scaling of the numeric variables like that:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion, make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

class Columns(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, names=None):
        self.names = names

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X.loc[:,self.names]

dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
dataset.columns = ["cat1", "cat2", "num1", "target"]

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3]

labelencoder_X_0 = LabelEncoder()
X.iloc[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_0.fit_transform(X.iloc[:, 0])

labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X.iloc[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X.iloc[:, 1])

numeric = ["num1"]
categorical = ["cat1", "cat2"]

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("features", FeatureUnion([
        ('numeric', make_pipeline(Columns(names=numeric),StandardScaler())),
        ('categorical', make_pipeline(Columns(names=categorical), OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)))
    ])),
])

X = pipe.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
# classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=25, criterion='entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='minkowski', p=2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

accuracy = classifier.score(X_test, y_test) 
print(accuracy)

Out: 
0.7101449275362319
```

As you see this brings the accuracy at least into the ball park of the Random Forrest!

So what you could try out next is to try the gower distance. There is an ongoing discussion of adding it to sklearn [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5884), so may check out the posted code there in the Ipython Notebook and try that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It indeed made a good change.
I still have one more questions though.. 

Once I add more data than what I previously posted: https://pastebin.com/ak2yaCrQ

It seems to drive the results back to what they were before. Why is that?

Comment: Mh, so I quickly checked with the Random Forrest, and its accuracy dropped now as well with the new data, and both are still in the same ball park now. So I don't think it is a programming issue anymore (hence not relevant to this thread at SO). So maybe dig deeper in what is different in the new data, e.g. check distributions of class labes to see if classes are balanced, and consider methods to takle this if they are not. Then think about your metric. Is accuracy suitable for you problem? Lots of stuff to do now :)

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into it. 

I also tried removing the price column.. Does not seem to help either.
One this that is bothering me is that when I test the classifier with a record that resides in the dataset it outputs an incorrect y variable. 

For example: Patio & Lawn & Garden,Garden Sculptures & Statues - (which belongs to 30) - outputs 26.

How come?

Comment: I assum "a record that resides in the dataset" refers to the train set? Well, on the trainset you currently have 76% (which btw indicates overfitting, giving the 62% on the test set). So even for the trainset it gets 24% wrong! Thats expected. For KNN this is due to averaging the k most similar instances in of the trains set. So as said, it's not a programmin issue, but modelling iteratively and digging deeper into problem.

Comment: (+1) and an edit from me, since I removed my own answer (somehow I missed completely the one-hot encoding...)

Comment: I've balanced the data and moved to RF with 10 estimators. Right now all the classes have ~10 samples. https://pastebin.com/z3eZc0vK
Still RF with low accuracy. What can be causing this? To me it seems like much more can be done here. Am I wrong?

Comment: It could be many things to do to improve your model (adding features, adding data, improving modelling parameters, trying different models, ...), so keep reading in the endless blogs and tutorial if it is of importance to achieve higher accuracy. It may, however, be, that it, in the end, is not really predictable "enough" (whatever it means in your case). But I think this is getting off-topic and too broad for SO - unless you think you find another programming bug, then consider another question. Good luck!